# Pierdo valor de variable de otra pagina en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Pagina 1**

En la página 1 cargo la variable que necesito pasar a la segunda página, la variable que necesito pasar es "mod_id" que está como un hidden

```html
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body">

    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" method="post" id="upd" name="upd">
      <div id="result2"></div>
      <input type="hidden" name="mod_id" id="mod_id">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">No Expediente</span>
                </label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <input name="mod_file" id="mod_file" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">No Expediente Viejo</span>
                </label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <input name="mod_file_old" id="mod_file_old" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Origen</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <input name="mod_category_id" id="mod_category_id" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Bagón</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <input name="mod_bagon_id_selectpicker" id="mod_bagon_id_selectpicker" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Caja</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <input name="mod_box_id_selectpicker" id="mod_box_id_selectpicker" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Observaciones</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <textarea name="mod_description" id="mod_description" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Usuario Creó</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <input name="mod_user_create" id="mod_user_create" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Fecha Creación</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <input name="mod_created_at" id="mod_created_at" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Usuario Actualizó</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <input name="mod_user_update" id="mod_user_update" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Fecha Actualizó</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <input name="mod_date_update" id="mod_date_update" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Estado</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <input name="mod_active" id="mod_active" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Esta primera parte se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debajo de esta parte cargo una la siguiente lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla debe carga todos los registros que tengan el mismo valor de **"mod_id"** sin embargo no lo hace sino que muestra todos los registro de la tabla, si hago el WHERE para que lo filtre con el siguiente código en la página 2

**Página 2**

```html
<?php
$projects = mysqli_query($con, "select * from project");
$priorities = mysqli_query($con, "select * from priority");
$statuses = mysqli_query($con, "select * from status");
$kinds = mysqli_query($con, "select * from kind");
$files = mysqli_query($con, "select * from file");
?>

  <div class="">
    <div class="page-title">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        <div class="x_panel">
          <div class="x_title">
            <h2>Folios </h2>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

          <!-- form search -->
          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <input type="hidden" name="view" value="reports">
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="fa fa-file"></i></span>
                  <select name="file_id" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                    <option value="">EXPEDIENTE</option>
                    <?php foreach ($files as $p): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>">
                      <?php echo $p['file']; ?>
                      <?php
                                            if (isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"] == $p['id']) {
                                                echo "selected";
                                            }
                                            ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i></span>
                  <select name="project_id" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                    <option value="">DEPARTAMENTO</option>
                    <?php foreach ($projects as $p): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>" <?php if (isset($_GET[ "project_id"]) && $_GET[ "project_id"]==$ p[ 'id']) { echo "selected"; } ?>>
                      <?php echo $p['name']; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-support"></i></span>
                  <select name="priority_id" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                    <option value="">PRIORIDAD</option>
                    <?php foreach ($priorities as $p): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>" <?php if (isset($_GET[ "priority_id"]) && $_GET[ "priority_id"]==$ p[ 'id']) { echo "selected"; } ?>>
                      <?php echo $p['name']; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
                  <select name="status_id" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                    <option value="">ESTADO</option>
                    <?php foreach ($statuses as $p): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>" <?php if (isset($_GET[ "status_id"]) && $_GET[ "status_id"]==$ p[ 'id']) { echo "selected"; } ?>>
                      <?php echo $p['name']; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i></span>
                  <select name="kind_id" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                    <option value="">TRAMITE</option>
                    <?php foreach ($kinds as $p): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>" <?php if (isset($_GET[ "kind_id"]) && $_GET[ "kind_id"]==$ p[ 'id']) { echo "selected"; } ?>>
                      <?php echo $p['name']; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">INICIO</span>
                  <input type="date" name="start_at" value="<?php
                                if (isset($_GET[" start_at "]) && $_GET["start_at "] != " ") {
                                    echo $_GET["start_at "];
                                }
                                ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Palabra clave">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">FIN</span>
                  <input type="date" name="finish_at" value="<?php
                                if (isset($_GET[" finish_at "]) && $_GET["finish_at "] != " ") {
                                    echo $_GET["finish_at "];
                                }
                                ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Palabra clave">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Procesar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <!-- end form search -->

          <?php
                $mod_id = isset($_GET['mod_id']) ? $_GET['mod_id'] : '';
                $users = array();
                if ((isset($_GET["file_id"]) &&
                        isset($_GET["project_id"]) &&
                        isset($_GET["priority_id"]) &&
                        isset($_GET["status_id"]) &&
                        isset($_GET["kind_id"]) &&
                        isset($_GET["start_at"]) &&
                        isset($_GET["finish_at"])) &&
                        ($_GET["file_id"] != "" ||
                        $_GET["project_id"] != "" ||
                        $_GET["priority_id"] != "" ||
                        $_GET["status_id"] != "" ||
                        $_GET["kind_id"] != "" ||
                        ($_GET["start_at"] != "" ||
                        $_GET["finish_at"] != ""))) {

                    $sql = "select * from document where ";

                    if ($_GET["file_id"] != "") {
                        if ($_GET["status_id"] != "" && $_GET["kind_id"] != "" && $_GET["priority_id"] != "" && $_GET["project_id"] != "") {
                            $sql .= " and ";
                        }
                        $sql .= " file_id = " . $_GET["file_id"];
                    }

                    if ($_GET["project_id"] != "") {
                        if ($_GET["status_id"] != "" && $_GET["kind_id"] != "" && $_GET["priority_id"] != "" && $_GET["file_id"] != "") {
                            $sql .= " and ";
                        }
                        $sql .= " project_id = " . $_GET["project_id"];
                    }

                    if ($_GET["priority_id"] != "") {
                        if ($_GET["status_id"] != "" || $_GET["kind_id"] != "" || $_GET["project_id"] != "" && $_GET["file_id"] != "") {
                            $sql .= " and ";
                        }
                        $sql .= " priority_id = " . $_GET["priority_id"];
                    }

                    if ($_GET["status_id"] != "") {
                        if ($_GET["priority_id"] != "" || $_GET["project_id"] != "" || $_GET["kind_id"] != "" && $_GET["file_id"] != "") {
                            $sql .= " and ";
                        }
                        $sql .= " status_id = " . $_GET["status_id"];
                    }

                    if ($_GET["kind_id"] != "") {
                        if ($_GET["status_id"] != "" || $_GET["priority_id"] != "" || $_GET["project_id"] != "" && $_GET["file_id"] != "") {
                            $sql .= " and ";
                        }
                        $sql .= " kind_id = " . $_GET["kind_id"];
                    }

                    if ($_GET["start_at"] != "" && $_GET["finish_at"] != "") {
                        if ($_GET["status_id"] != "" || $_GET["project_id"] != "" || $_GET["priority_id"] != "" || $_GET["kind_id"] != "" && $_GET["file_id"] != "") {
                            $sql .= " and ";
                        }
                        $sql .= "( created_at >= \"" . $_GET["start_at"] . "\" and created_at <= \"" . $_GET["finish_at"] . "\" ) ";
                    }

                    $users = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                } else {
                    $users = mysqli_query($con, "select * from document WHERE file_id = $mod_id order by created_at desc");
                }
                var_dump($mod_id);

                if (@mysqli_num_rows($users) > 0) {
                    // si hay reportes
                    $_SESSION["report_data"] = $users;
                    ?>
            <div class="x_content">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <!--<th>Consecutivo</th>-->
                    <th>N° Expediente</th>
                    <th>Asunto</th>
                    <th>Departamento</th>
                    <th>Trámite</th>
                    <th>Origen</th>
                    <th>Prioridad</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>Asignado a</th>
                    <th>Ingresado</th>
                    <th>Ultima Actualización</th>
                  </thead>
                  <?php
                                $total = 0;
                                foreach ($users as $user) {
                                    $id = $user['id'];
                                    $consecutive = $user['consecutive'];
                                    $file_id = $user['file_id'];
                                    $title = $user['title'];
                                    $description = $user['description'];
                                    $sheets = $user['sheets'];
                                    $filecase_id = $user['filecase_id'];
                                    $sender_id = $user['sender_id'];
                                    $kind_id = $user['kind_id'];
                                    $project_id = $user['project_id'];
                                    $category_id = $user['category_id'];
                                    $team_id = $user['team_id'];
                                    $assigned_to = $user['assigned_to'];
                                    $priority_id = $user['priority_id'];
                                    $status_id = $user['status_id'];
                                    $attach_id = $user['attach_id'];
                                    $way_id = $user['way_id'];
                                    $user_update = $user['user_update'];
                                    $date_update = $user['date_update'];
                                    $craft = $user['craft'];
                                    $datecraft = date('d/m/Y h:i', strtotime($user['datecraft']));
                                    $user_received = $user['user_received'];
                                    $received = $user['received'];
                                    $user_create = $user['user_create'];
                                    $created_at = date('d/m/Y h:i', strtotime($user['created_at']));

                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from file where id = $file_id");
                                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                        $file = $c['file'];
                                    }

                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from sender where id = $sender_id");
                                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                        $name_sender = $c['name'];
                                    }

                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from kind where id = $kind_id");
                                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                        $name_kind = $c['name'];
                                    }

                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from user where id = $user_create");
                                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                        $name_user_id = $c['name'];
                                    }

                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from document where project_id in (" . $project_id . ")");

                                    if ($project_id <= 1) {

                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                            $array = $row['project_id'];
                                            $array1 = explode(',', $array);

                                            $code = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM project WHERE id = $array1");

                                            if ($code = '') {
                                                $project = '';
                                                foreach ($code["name"] as $row) {
                                                    $project .= $row . ', ';
                                                }
                                                $project = substr($project, 0, -2);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else {

                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                            $array = $row['project_id'];
                                            $array1 = explode(',', $array);
                                            $project = '';

                                            foreach ($array1 as $id_array) {
                                                $code = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM project WHERE id = $id_array");

                                                while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($code)) {
                                                    $project .= $row1['name'] . ', ';
                                                }
                                            }
                                            $project = substr($project, 0, -2);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from document where assigned_to in (" . $assigned_to . ")");

                                    if ($assigned_to <= 1) {

                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                            $array = $row['assigned_to'];
                                            $array1 = explode(',', $array);

                                            $code = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $array1");

                                            if ($code = '') {
                                                $users = '';
                                                foreach ($code["name"] as $row) {
                                                    $users .= $row . ', ';
                                                }
                                                $users = substr($users, 0, -2);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else {

                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                            $array = $row['assigned_to'];
                                            $array1 = explode(',', $array);
                                            $users = '';

                                            foreach ($array1 as $id_array) {
                                                $code = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $id_array");

                                                while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($code)) {
                                                    $users .= $row1['name'] . ', ';
                                                }
                                            }
                                            $users = substr($users, 0, -2);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from category where id = $category_id");
                                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                        $name_category = $c['name'];
                                    }

//                                        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from filecase where id = $filecase_id");
//                                        if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
//                                            $name_filecase_id = $c['name'];
//                                        }

                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from priority where id = $priority_id");
                                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                        $name_priority = $c['name'];
                                    }

                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from status where id = $status_id");
                                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                        $name_status = $c['name'];
                                    }

                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from attach where id = $attach_id");
                                    if ($a = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                        $name_attach = $a['name'];
                                    }

                                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from way where id = $way_id");
                                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                        $name_way_id = $c['name'];
                                    }
                                    ?>

                    <tr>
                      <!--<td><?php // echo $consecutive          ?></td>-->
                      <td>
                        <?php echo $file ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php echo $title ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php echo $project ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php echo $name_kind ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php echo $name_category ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php echo $name_priority ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php echo $name_status ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php echo $users ?>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <?php echo date('d/m/Y h:i', strtotime($created_at)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php
                                            if ($date_update != NULL) {
                                                echo date('d/m/Y h:i', strtotime($date_update));
                                            } else {
                                                echo date('d/m/Y h:i', strtotime($created_at));
                                            }
                                            ?>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                      <?php
                            } else {
                                echo "<p class='alert alert-danger'>No hay documentos para mostrar</p>";
                            }
                            ?>
                </table>

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /page content -->
```

Pero pierde el valor de la variable mod_id y como se ve con el var_dum ($mod_id) es NULL y lo que muestra en pantalla es lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El metodo del form es `post` y lo intentas leer con `$_GET`

Comment: Lo modifique y no hace ninguna diferencia

Comment: ¿como le das valor? en el código que muestras no tiene valor.  Quita lo de `hidden` verifica que tiene el valor que crees que debería.

Comment: Lo llamo con el botón a través de un ajax y carga los datos asi <script>function obtener_datos(id) {var file = $("#file" + id).val();$("#mod_id").val(id);}</script> en otra pagina

Comment: Saludos, puedes agregar la parte de como envias los datos de "pagina1" a "pagina2".. para poder entender mejor

Answer (score 0):

El input mod_id no tiene valor asignado, tienes que agregar el atributo value="algun_valor" para que se envíe a la otra página:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mod_id" id="mod_id" value="algo">
```